# Why is Identity Provider button missing at Portal UI

Tags: gravitee

I am running Gravitee 3.9 in Docker containers (apim-portal-ui, apim-management-ui, apim-management-api, apim-gateway).

No matter what I do I am unable to make buttons for authentication via external identity provider appear at the sign-in screen of *portal-ui*, although I **can** see them at sign-in screen of *management-ui*. How can I make those buttons appear at the *portal-ui* too?

Observations:

- When I go to "Organization Settings/Authentication", I can see that both of my Identity Providers are Activated, they are also ticked in the column "Available for Portal" and button "Show login form on management console" is also ticked.
- When following the official documentation, there are also pictures showing "Settings/Authentication" section, but this section is entirely missing from my *management-ui* (it should be between sections *API Quality* and *Categories*, but there is nothing there).

Answer (score 1):

You would also need to enable the setting under Settings -> Portal -> Authentication. See the image below.

[image: Portal settings]